# Is there a function like "int" or "float" but for prime numbers?

Tags: c++, primes

The question might be unclear, what I'm asking and searching for is this: in C++ programming one introduces the type of the variabile with commands

- int, for integer
- bool, for boolean
- double
- float

and so on..

I wondered if there is a similar way to define the "prime" like

prime n;

so then when he program will recall $n$, it automatically will take only prime numbers.

An application of that with a simple program: supposing I want to create a list of the integer part of the operation

π^n

where π = Pi and n = prime number.
Mathematically it would be

Floor[π^n]

No, I now how to write a program to list some prime numbers, for example:

```
    int main () 
{
    for (int i=2; i<100; i++) 
    {
        bool prime=true;
        for (int j=2; j*j<=i; j++)
        {
            if (i % j == 0) 
            {
                prime=false;
                break;    
            }
        }   
        if(prime) cout << i << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

But I am not really sure of how to continue.. Also I'm sorry for my bad way to express what I would like to do!

Comment: Is this a C question or a C++ question? Or is it specifically about C++11? Your tags conflict.

Comment: What operations would be supported?  I guess multiply is out?

Comment: You do know that knowing if something is a prime-number (for large numbers) is computationally quite difficult, right?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz actually I'm open to C and C++ the same, so I tagged them both (just to have a larger range of options). ^^

Comment: @KimPeek Well, the simple answer is: No, there's no such thing for any of the languages you have tagged.

Comment: @MatsPetersson I do know, but maybe my question was not clear.. I want to create a program which takes Pi (3.141592..) to the N-th power, where N are ONLY prime numbers, start from π^2 then π^3 then π^5 and so on, and then operating the Floor function.

Finally, that has to list the obtained values, which are for example: 9, 31, 306, 3020...

Comment: Neither the C nor the C++ standard specify such a type. You can write your own user-defined type in C++ that has the properties you look for, but it will probably require dynamic execution; I don't know of any hardware that has a built-in concept of primes.

Comment: Assuming reasonable size of N, I'd say that this is best done by hard-coding an array with the values of N that you wish to use. It's not like the first million(s) of prime numbers are that hard to come by in a form that can easily be added to your program.

Comment: Ok ok, there wasn't, anyway, this need to downvote! If you guys came to Mathematics Stack Exchange asking for a question, even if dumb or silly I wouldn't ever down vote you!!

Comment: @KimPeek “I'm open to C and C++”—this is not how it works. You choose a programming language, we give an answer for that programming language. Otherwise your question cannot be answered because one has to be an expert in both C and C++ to be sure that the answer is “no” for both.

Comment: @FUZxxl Ok then, C++ be!

Answer (score 1):

The Answer regarding all mentioned language tags is No.

Primes are included in int since all primes are integer numbers.

Finding whether an integer number is also prime requires an algorithm implemented in a function.

Suppose that prime type exists and you initialize it with a vulue of 4 which isn't prime...the compiler should say something like a type mismatch and not allow you to run the program.
sounds pretty simple so far but what happens when there's a really big number. it has to apply an algorithm which means it's no longer a compiler problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are some specialised languages and libraries. For example [Pari/Gp](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/) which has a nice interpreter with many prime related functions (the interpreter calls into a C-library, so its fast): For examples

```
primes(100)
```

gives you the vector of the first 100 primes. There is even a primality test with `isprime`. It is really nice and easy to start playing around with. When you interested in heavy algebraic number theory stuff, that is possible too. Your example:

```
P = precision(Pi, 1000)
vector(100, i, floor((P^prime(i))))
```

The first line create PI with a high enough precision for exponentiation, the second line creates a list with the evaluation of floor(Pi^p) with p ranging over ther first 100 primes.

There is a program `gp2c` which translates your high level gp interpreter scripts into compileable C-Programs using the underlying library. You can use that when you need more speed, but for a start: use the gp Interpreter.

There are other packages as well, I would also recommend [SAGE](http://www.sagemath.org/). It is an Open Source alternative to Maple and Mathematica. SAGE uses Python as its scripting language, here you would use:

```
for p in primes_first_n(100): print p

[ floor( pi^p ) for p in primes_first_n(100) ]
```

You can try it out by creating an account for the [online version of SAGE](https://cloud.sagemath.com/)

Answer (score -1):

No my friend, there is not any option like whatever you ask.
But there is some way for that:
First, use Structure, Union, Typedef these are used to create data type in c lang

or else, Second, create a function prime() and add to library, and whenever you want include that header file and then use that fxn
Add User-Define function to library (using tlib.exe-TurboLibrarian):-
Info:-in cmd- tlib math.lib + c:\prime.obj (NOTE: use '-' to delete fxn from library)
How to use:
#include< math.h>
........................
........................
prime(n)
 blah blah blah
........................
By this way you can check prime no very quickly and add those to array, then you will have an array containing only prime no(same as datatype accepting prime no)

COOL NO?